# Show that specific polynomial with $p(a)=p(b)=0$ must be constantly $0$.

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, functional-equations

> Say polynomial $p\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ is such that for all
> reals $x,y,z$ such that $xy+yz+zx = 0$, we have
> $$ p(x-y) + p(y-z) + p(z-x) = 2p(x+y+z). $$
> Prove that $p(x)=0$ for all $x$ if $p(a) = p(b)=0$ for some
> different positive $a$ and $b$, **without explicitly solving the
> equation.**

> To make it easier, you can choose $a,b$ on your own **explicitly**.

All I can get is
\begin{align}
 x=y=z=0: &\;\; 3p(0)=2p(0) \implies \boxed{p(0) =0}\\
 x=y=0 : &\;\; p(-z)+p(z) =2p(z) \implies \boxed{p(-z) =p(z),\;\; \forall z}\\
\end{align}
so $p$ is an even polynomial with constant term $0$. From $p(a)=p(b)=0$ we can say that $\deg (p)\geq 6$.

I can't find anything usefull from here.

Comment: Just in case. The original problem can be found here https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h14021p99448 (I'm sure that OP knows about that)

Answer (score 3):

Set $x=6t$, $y=3t$, and $z=-2t$. Then

$$xy+yz+zx=18t^2-6t^2-12t^2=0$$

and

$$p(x-y)+p(y-z)+p(z-x)=2p(x+y+z)$$

$$p(3t)+p(5t)+p(-8t)=2p(7t)$$

Then with your observation that $p(t)=p(-t)$, this simplifies to

$$p(3t)+p(5t)+p(8t)=2p(7t)$$

Now, we know that if the polynomial is not identically zero, then for very large $t$ (past all the zeros)

$$1=\frac{2p(7t)}{p(3t)+p(5t)+p(8t)}$$

If we denote the leading coefficient of $p(t)$ by $a$, then

$$1=\frac{2p(7t)}{p(3t)+p(5t)+p(8t)}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{2p(7t)}{p(3t)+p(5t)+p(8t)}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{2a7^nt^n}{a3^nt^n+a5^nt^n+a8^nt^n}$$

(where $n$ is the degree of $p(t)$). This simplifies to

$$=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{2a7^nt^n}{a3^nt^n+a5^nt^n+a8^nt^n}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{2\cdot 7^n}{3^n+5^n+8^n}=\frac{2\cdot 7^n}{3^n+5^n+8^n}$$

Now, is this equation ever satisfied? Yes, at $n=2$ and $n=4$. However, you showed in your question that $n\geq 6$ (this is where we use the fact that $p(a)=p(b)=0$ for some $a,b>0$). But for these $n$ we have

$$\frac{2\cdot 7^n}{3^n+5^n+8^n}<2\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)^n\leq 2\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)^6=\frac{117649}{131072}<1$$

Thus, the polynomial must be identically zero.

Comment: Actually we can find now a solution for $p$ since we know what is it degree.

Comment: There is a degree 2 solution, namely $ p(x) = Ax^2$ (no surprise there), but I don't think there is a degree 4 solution --> Setting $p(x) = Ax^2 (x-a)^2$ doesn't seem to result in terms cancelling out.